# Linking two instances of the same table in a query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, migrate

I have a table of sales orders tied to a sales organization currency and a costing plant that may or may not have a different currency.  I have an exchange rate table that list the rates for different currency pairs.  I need to link the exchange rate table to the sales currency and separately to the cost currency.  When I try to link the exchange table twice, I get and error message I get this error -

> the objects "dbo.VW_CurrrentExchange" and "dbo.VW_CurrentExchange" in
>   the FROM clause have the same exposed names.  Use correlation names to
>   distinguish them.

I've tried linking the table twice, giving the table an additional name (as it is in Access, e.g., `dbo.VW_CurrentExchange_1`) and simply modelling what was in Access.

```
select dbo.SalesOrderItems.DV, dbo.SalesOrderItems.SOrg, dbo.SalesOrderItems.SalesDoc, dbo.SalesOrderItems.item, dbo.SalesOrderItems.itca, dbo.SalesOrderItems.rj, dbo.SalesOrderItems.Createdon1 as ItemCreation, dbo.SalesOrderItems.[Sold-topt] as SoldTo, dbo.SalesOrderItems.OrderQuantity, dbo.SalesOrderItems.Cumulconfirmedqty as CCQSU,  dbo.SalesOrderItems.SU, dbo.SalesOrderItems.Cumulconfirmedqty1 as CCQBU, dbo.SalesOrderItems.BUn, dbo.SalesOrderItems.Material, dbo.SalesOrderItems.Plnt as Plant, dbo.SalesOrderItems.Reqdlvdt as RDD, dbo.SalesOrderItems.Netprice, dbo.SalesOrderItems.per, dbo.SalesOrderItems.RSD, dbo.SalesOrderItemStatus.DS , dbo.SalesOrderItemStatus.DS1 , dbo.SalesOrderItemStatus.DS2 , dbo.SalesOrderItemStatus.DS3, dbo.SalesOrderItemStatus.GM, dbo.SalesOrderItemStatus.OvCS, dbo.SalesOrderItemStatus.OS, dbo.SalesOrderItemStatus.DB, dbo.SalesOrderItemStatus.DB1, dbo.SalesOrderItemStatus.GS, dbo.SalesOrderItemStatus.BS, dbo.SalesOrderItemStatus.Rejectionstatus, dbo.customers.Name3, dbo.MARA.MaterialDescription, dbo.MARA.MatlGroup, dbo.MARC.ProfitCtr, dbo.VW_CurrentExchange.Exchange as PExch, dbl.VW_CurrentExchange.exchange as CExch           

from dbo.SalesOrderItems join  dbo.SalesOrderItemStatus on dbo.SalesOrderItems.salesdoc =  dbo.SalesOrderItemStatus.salesdoc and dbo.salesorderitems.item = SalesOrderItemStatus.item join dbo.VW_CurrentExchange on dbo.salesorderitems.curr = dbo.vw_currentexchange.Currency2 join dbo.customers on dbo.SalesOrderItems.[Sold-topt]=dbo.customers.Customer join dbo.MARA on dbo.SalesOrderItems.Material = dbo.MARA.Material join dbo.MARC on dbo.SalesOrderItems.Material = dbo.MARC.material and dbo.SalesOrderItems.plnt=dbo.MARC.Plnt join dbo.MBEW on dbo.SalesOrderItems.Material= dbo.MBEW.Material and dbo.SalesOrderItems.plnt=dbo.MBEW.ValA join dbo.Plants on dbo.SalesOrderItems.plnt = dbo.Plants.Plnt join dbo.VW_CurrentExchange on dbo.SalesOrderItems.curr = dbo.VW_CurrentExchange.Currency2

order by dbo.salesorderitems.Createdon1 desc
```

would hope to get the fields listed including PExch and CExch, but get Msg 1013,

> Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The objects
>   "dbo.VW_CurrentExchange" and "dbo.VW_CurrentExchange" in the FROM
>   clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to
>   distinguish them.

Comment: Please use a different aliases to the tables and try the same code

Comment: Could you post the query that didn't work where you used the VW_CurrentExchange_1 alias?

Answer (score 0):

Linking the table twice is the wrong thing to do. Instead, as suggested by @indika-ranaweera in comments, what you want to do is use the SAME linked table in your SQL, but give it an alias.

In fact, giving your tables aliases *all the time* is good practice and makes it possible to actually *read* your SQL rather than relying on a graphic query editor like Access provides.

I reformatted your SQL with http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm, added aliases, made what I hope is a smart guess about the two uses of `VW_CurrentExchange`, and got the following result:

```
SELECT SOI.dv, 
       SOI.sorg, 
       SOI.salesdoc, 
       SOI.item, 
       SOI.itca, 
       SOI.rj, 
       SOI.createdon1         AS ItemCreation, 
       SOI.[sold-topt]        AS SoldTo, 
       SOI.orderquantity, 
       SOI.cumulconfirmedqty  AS CCQSU, 
       SOI.su, 
       SOI.cumulconfirmedqty1 AS CCQBU, 
       SOI.bun, 
       SOI.material, 
       SOI.plnt               AS Plant, 
       SOI.reqdlvdt           AS RDD, 
       SOI.netprice, 
       SOI.per, 
       SOI.rsd, 
       SOIS.ds, 
       SOIS.ds1, 
       SOIS.ds2, 
       SOIS.ds3, 
       SOIS.gm, 
       SOIS.ovcs, 
       SOIS.os, 
       SOIS.db, 
       SOIS.db1, 
       SOIS.gs, 
       SOIS.bs, 
       SOIS.rejectionstatus, 
       C.name3, 
       MARA.materialdescription, 
       MARA.matlgroup, 
       MARC.profitctr, 
       VCE1.exchange        AS PExch, 
       VCE2.exchange        AS CExch 
FROM   dbo.salesorderitems AS SOI
       JOIN dbo.salesorderitemstatus AS SOIS
     ON SOI.salesdoc = SOIS.salesdoc 
        AND SOI.item = salesorderitemstatus.item 
       JOIN dbo.vw_currentexchange AS VCE1
     ON SOI.curr = VCE1.currency2 
       JOIN dbo.customers AS C
     ON SOI.[sold-topt] = C.customer 
       JOIN dbo.mara AS MARA
     ON SOI.material = MARA.material 
       JOIN dbo.marc AS MARC
     ON SOI.material = MARC.material 
        AND SOI.plnt = MARC.plnt 
       JOIN dbo.mbew AS MBEW
     ON SOI.material = MBEW.material 
        AND SOI.plnt = MBEW.vala 
       JOIN dbo.plants AS P
     ON SOI.plnt = P.plnt 
       JOIN dbo.vw_currentexchange AS VCE2
     ON SOI.curr = VCE2.currency2 
ORDER  BY SOI.createdon1 DESC
```

---

EDIT: After reviewing what I posted, I don't see the reason that you need two copies of vw_currentexchange. They are both related by the same exact fields (`curr` to `currency2`). Maybe one of them should be `currency1` ?